# Transferring new Date from Javascript in Chrome to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Javascript console when running `new Date()` it returns something like:

```
Wed Jan 13 2021 18:30:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

but in node.js it returns:

```
2021-01-13T18:32:21.182Z
```

So my question is, how in node.js would I get time in the format of the browser? Is the only way to format it like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)?

Comment: Why does it matter that `console.log` formats dates differently in the two environments? It's still exactly the same date.

Comment: @HereticMonkey as stated in the question I'm trying to see if there's an alternative.

Comment: @Bergi - my use case requires it to be in that exact format.

Comment: That question has **73 answers** I think that's plenty of alternatives.

Comment: The browser console gets its format from [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString). Notice that this depends on the local timezone.

Comment: @Bergi - thank you this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `toUTCString()`

```js
console.log(new Date().toUTCString())
```

It will return you the time in the UTC format that you want.

Comment: Yes, this definitely takes me a lot closer, is there any way to get the `GMT+0000 (Greenwich Meantime)` section as well?